# Why can't I "multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'"?

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
Hours = raw_input('Enter the value of Hours: \n')
Rate = raw_input('Enter the value of Rate: \n')
Pay = Hours * Rate
round (Pay, 2)
print Pay
```

Result is: at line 4
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `raw_input` returns a `str` and you want an `int`. You can fix this:

```
Hours = int(raw_input('Enter the value of Hours: \n'))
Rate = int(raw_input('Enter the value of Rate: \n'))
Pay = Hours * Rate
Pay = round(Pay, 2)
print Pay
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a string when you use raw_input.
If you want an int use int(raw_input('text'))